# How to calculate the frequency of this python list?

Tags: python

I have a list of python list like this:

```
base_list (About 3,000,000 sub lists):

[
   ['Hello','World','Lucy','Lily'],
   ['Hello','Smith','Simpson','Bart'],
   ....
]
```

Now i get a small list:

```
small_list:

['Hello','World']
```

Now, i need to find out how many times the small_list appears in the base_list.

**Appear** means this : [1,3] is appears in [1,2,3,4,5] .

**UPDATE**

I've tried this:

1.Change the base_list into a list of set.

2.Then, change the small_list into a set too:

```
def get_original_freq(self, actors):
    count = 0
    s = set(actors)
    for row in self.orignal_rows:
      if s.issubset(row):
        count += 1
    return count
```

But the code runs really slow, about 1000 records have been checked per second.

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive.

Comment: You have been here for a while buddy, you should know how this works by now

Comment: @Sheena I'm sorry, my english is poor. Sometimes i try to avoid mistakes(post short questions) which always makes things worse. I'll fix from now on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find out the **Inverted Index** helps me out:

1.Make the base_list become a inverted index:

```
{
    'Hello': [1,5,10,8000]
    'World': [1,2,3,5,9]
    ...
}
```

2.When i need to count the ['Hello','World']'s count number of appearances. I just find the two inverted index of them and count their common documents.

Answer (score 0):

My first reaction is to answer with a silly (albeit working) answer:

```
def sublistCount(listA, listB):
    if not len(listB):
        return 0
    conditions = ["%s in a" % repr(b) for b in listB]
    comprehension = '[a for a in listA if %s]' % ' and '.join(conditions)
    return len(eval(comprehension))
```

where listA is the list of lists and listB is the sublist.

This is actually pretty fast, even when working with lists of strings. I ran through a list of 3,000,000 lists of strings in about 1-2 seconds.

I called it silly because it's using the eval() function to create code on the fly. If you're not sure what your input will be, this could be potentially dangerous. This solution is the bassoon of the orchestra of possible solutions: it's funny, it works, but just one bad note or squeak makes it all bad.

However, my favorite of the potential solutions is this:

```
def sublistCount(listA, listB):
    b = set(listB)
    matches = [a for a in listA if b.issubset(a)]
    return len(matches)
```

This is safer, much cleaner, and performs nearly as well as the first solution (for 3,000,000 records).